# slick slider - стрелки, когда все слайды видны

Tags: slider, slick.js

Всем привет!) есть слайдер

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  draggable: true,
  swipe: true,
  arrows: true,
  loop: true
});
```

});

```
                    <div class="slide slider-nav">
                        <img src="/img/2015.png" alt="" class="img-slider-company">
                        <img src="/img/2015.png" alt="" class="img-slider-company">
                        <img src="/img/2015.png" alt="" class="img-slider-company">
                        <img src="/img/2015.png" alt="" class="img-slider-company">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide slider-for">
                        <p class="paragraph-slider paragraph-slider__company">
                            1 9001:2015, ГАЗСЕРТ Новая модель крана «под задвижку»
                        </p>
                        <p class="paragraph-slider paragraph-slider__company">
                            2 9001:2015, ГАЗСЕРТ Новая модель крана «под задвижку»
                        </p>
                        <p class="paragraph-slider paragraph-slider__company">
                            3 ISO 9001:2015, ГАЗСЕРТ Новая модель крана «под задвижку»
                        </p>
                        <p class="paragraph-slider paragraph-slider__company">
                            4 ISO 9001:2015, ГАЗСЕРТ Новая модель крана «под задвижку»
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

Когда количество слайдов равно slidesToShow - стрелки пропадают..
Скажите плз, как их можно вернуть для перелистывания слайдов?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score -1):

Извиняюсь, разобрался

```
centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '180px'
```